# Add support for new data type (quantiphy.Quantity)

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm having a Pydantic model which includes a custom data tpye (specifically `quantiphy.Quantity`):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class SpecLimit(BaseModel):
    label: str
    minimum: Quantity | None = None
    maximum: Quantity | None = None
    typical: Quantity | None = None
    is_informative: bool = False
```

I want Pydantic to serialize the `Quantity` objects as string (and de-serialize them from strings), but I can't figure out how. I always end up with:
`pydantic.errors.PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for <class 'quantiphy.quantiphy.Quantity'>...`

I've tried to specify a `json_encoder`, but this doesn't work and the `json_encoders` attribute is deprecated.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel as _BaseModel
from quantiphy import Quantity


class BaseModel(_BaseModel):
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            Quantity: str,
        }

class SpecLimit(BaseModel):
    label: str
    minimum: Quantity | None = None
    maximum: Quantity | None = None
    typical: Quantity | None = None
    is_informative: bool = False
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this using Python pydantic is to use the `@validator` decorator of pydantic and the `parse_raw` method as the example below, let's guess you only have the `minimum` field for this example, so you can do this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from quantiphy import Quantity

class SpecLimit(BaseModel):
    minimum: Quantity | None = None

    @validator("minimum", pre=True, always=True)
    def serialize_quantity(cls, value):
        if value is not None:
            return str(value)
        return value

    @validator("minimum", pre=False, always=True)
    def deserialize_quantity(cls, value):
        if value is not None and isinstance(value, str):
            return Quantity(value)
        return value
```

Then the use of this example is:

#### Serialize to JSON

```
spec_limit = SpecLimit(minimum=Quantity("10 kg"))
print(spec_limit.json())
```

#### Deserialize from JSON

```
json_data = '{"minimum": "20 g"}'
loaded_spec_limit = SpecLimit.parse_raw(json_data)
print(loaded_spec_limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on the deprecation warning you mentioned in your post, I presume you work with Pydantic v2.0. The most flexible pattern I found for working with external objects in Pydantic v2.0 is the following:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, PlainSerializer, ConfigDict
from pydantic.functional_validators import BeforeValidator
from quantiphy import Quantity
from typing import Optional, Annotated


def quantity_validator(value):
    return Quantity(value)

def quantity_serializer(value):
    return str(value)


QuantityType = Annotated[
    Quantity,
    PlainSerializer(quantity_serializer),
    BeforeValidator(quantity_validator),
 ]


class SpecLimit(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
    )

    label: str
    minimum: Optional[QuantityType] = None
    maximum: Optional[QuantityType] = None
    typical: Optional[QuantityType] = None
    is_informative: bool = False


spec_limit = SpecLimit(minimum="1.0m", maximum="2.0m", label='test')
data = spec_limit.model_dump()

SpecLimit.model_validate(data)
```

A couple of things to mention here:

- Pydantic internally creates a JSON schema for your model definition. The `Quantity` object is not known, so you have to use `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the config dict.
- While @Kfir Goldfarb proposal works, it is only valid for Pydantic v1.0 and more importantly you cannot re-use the type definition. So you would need to copy and paste the validator if you use Quantity in different places
- If you want to avoid the `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` you need to tell Pydantic how to create the JSON schema using `__get_pydantic_core_schema__`, which is a bit cumbersome. Still you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#customizing-validation-with-__get_pydantic_core_schema__)

I hope this helps!